# Css variables with twind.js

Tags: tailwind-css, tailwind-in-js, twind

I'm trying to add custom theme using twind, Is there any way to use css variables with https://twind.dev/?

Answer (score 0):

You could follow this one: https://twind.dev/handbook/configuration.html#theme

And rather than

```js
gray: colors.trueGray
```

you could use a CSS variable

```js
gray: 'var(--color-bluegray-300)'
```

Thanks to the variable from an upper scope.

Comment: It's not working. I've done this with tailwindcss before but the issue is twind is not recognizing extended colors somehow.

Comment: Maybe they do not have any `extend` and you should rely on writing all the colors by yourself.